# JavaFX - Mask text of a TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I would to know if there is a way to mask the text of a `TextArea` in JavaFX.
For example, masking the text using the 'bullet' password character like `PasswordField`. For `TextField`, there is the `maskText()` method that works well. This method is not useful for `TextArea`.
What can I do?

NB: I want that `getText()` and `setText()` method must work with the clear text, not with the masked text. Just like `PasswordField` works.

EDIT
That is the approach I used to achieve the result, but unfortunately unsuccessfully.

My custom `TextArea` class:

```
public class PasswordArea extends TextArea {

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new PasswordAreaSkin(this); //my custom skin
    }
}
```

the custom skin used for the custom `TextArea`:

```
public class PasswordAreaSkin extends TextAreaSkin {
    public PasswordAreaSkin(PasswordArea control) {
        super(control);
    }

    //here I override the maskText method to mask the text
    @Override
    protected String maskText(String text) {
        int n = text.length();
        StringBuilder passwordBuilder=new StringBuilder(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            passwordBuilder.append('\u2022'); //append 'bullet' char
        }

        return passwordBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since there is no built in method to mask the text, you will have to implement one yourself. Why and how do you want to mask text in a `TextArea`? The entire text or just parts of it (like single `String`s)?

Comment: I want that all the text inside the `TextArea` will be masked with the 'bullet' characters like the `PasswordField`. I tried to create a custom `TextArea` overriding the `maskText()` method unsuccessfully.

Comment: You cannot override a method that does not exist in the super class, can you? Please provide the code you have written so far in a minimal working (or failing) example.
My first approach would be extending `TextArea` that has a member (maybe just a `String`) that holds the real text and writing a method `maskText()`, which replaces every character with a bullet.

Comment: the `maskText()` method is a method of the class `TextInputControlSkin` I create a custom `TextArea` with a custom skin that extends `TextAreaSkin` (that 's a subclass of `TextInputControlSkin`)

Comment: Another reason for providing code here ;-)
Show your approach, if it just contains a small mistake, you have a good chance of getting that resolved together with this community.

Comment: @deHaar I edited the post adding the code. I don't think there is a mystake by myself. I thinks that JavaFX internally force text to be clear or simply ignore the maskText method. If it is the least option I think is a serious bad design choose. It was a bad use of inerithance when they design these JavaFX base classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you want is that `TextArea` is not built for this functionality, at least in JDK 8 (JDK 9 added public skinning API, e.g., [`TextAreaSkin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextAreaSkin.html)). Specifically, its skin, `TextAreaSkin` does not facilitated a masking mechanism.

`TextFieldSkin` does masking by binding the visual text node's `textProperty` to the component's `textProperty`. Thus, any change to the "real" text of the component manifests in the text of the visual component plus the appropriate masking modification (the `maskText` method):

```
textNode.textProperty().bind(new StringBinding() {
    { bind(textField.textProperty()); }
    @Override protected String computeValue() {
        return maskText(textField.textProperty().getValueSafe());
    }
});
```

`TextAreaSkin` uses a group of `Text` nodes for its visuals, though only 1 is used in JDK 8. Changes to the visual text are made by listening to changes in the component's text:

```
textArea.textProperty().addListener(observable -> {
    invalidateMetrics();
    ((Text)paragraphNodes.getChildren().get(0)).setText(textArea.textProperty().getValueSafe());
    contentView.requestLayout();
});
```

We can use this to listen to changes in the visual text and update it ourselves. Below is a working example of an implementation. The `maskText` method is mostly copied from `TextFieldSkin`. We use reflection to gain access to the visual text representation node and then update it with the current text (e.g., from the text area constructor) and register the update listener.

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String s = "some times there are\nmore strings\n\nin here";
        TextArea ta = new TextArea(s);
        ta.setSkin(new TextAreaMaskSkin(ta));

        TextArea view = new TextArea();
        view.textProperty().bind(ta.textProperty());

        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(view, ta));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static class TextAreaMaskSkin extends TextAreaSkin {

        public TextAreaMaskSkin(TextArea textArea) throws Exception {
            super(textArea);
            Field field = TextAreaSkin.class.getDeclaredField("paragraphNodes");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Group group = (Group) field.get(this);
            Text text = (Text) group.getChildren().get(0);
            text.setText(maskText(textArea.textProperty().getValueSafe()));
            text.textProperty().addListener(o -> text.setText(maskText(textArea.textProperty().getValueSafe())));
        }

        @Override
        protected String maskText(String txt) {
            int n = txt.length();
            StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (txt.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                    passwordBuilder.append('\n');
                } else {
                    passwordBuilder.append(TextFieldSkin.BULLET);
                }
            }
            return passwordBuilder.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you working with jdk8 or jdk9? Because with jdk9 I tried to use reflection but with the new module system I get some exceptions. I have not yet fully understood how to correcty works with reflection and module sistem.

Comment: @Vin This is with 8. You didn't mention what version you were using. You need to open the module you want access to in 9.

Comment: The solution I posted work both with jdk 8 and jdk9. The only "glitch" is that multiple clear text lines are converted in a single masked line (that is better than nothing for me now).

Comment: This one works for both versions as well, you just need to open the module. I don't understand your "glitch": what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I indented that if I write:some times\nmore text\nin strings the masked text results in *******************************, al in the same line. What I want, and you explained very well because it cannot happen, is that the masked text is distributed on the three lines.

Comment: @Vin I didn't say you can't have multiple lines masking. It's a matter of modifying `maskText` to ignore `\n`. See my edit. I just didn't see you specified that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could make every character appear as a "bullet" than have a separate string that would actually be the text.

Comment: It could not work because I should have to use the `setText()` method with a String contains as "bullet" character as text length. But this approach would break the `getTex()` method that would return the masked text (I want that `getText()` instead returns the clear text). In addition in JavaFX `setText()` and `getText()` are final methods so they cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around which does what you want (at least as far as I could follow your desires…). It uses a `ChangeListener` and manipulates the input while storing the original. For further manipulation or use, please extend the code yourself. Ah, and by the way: There is no need for a `Skin` now, but feel free to apply it, the masking is done in the `PasswordArea`. This may not be the most efficient solution, but it is working (when used in a `Main.java` like the one posted at the end of this answer).

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class PasswordArea extends TextArea {

    private StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder masked = new StringBuilder();

    public PasswordArea() {
        this.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            int oldLength = oldValue.length();
            int newLength = newValue.length();

            if (newLength == oldLength) {
                // obviously an unnecessary case to be checked
            } else if (newLength < oldLength) {
                // last character deleted, so delete the last one of each, original and masked text
                original.delete(newLength, oldLength);
                masked.delete(newLength, oldLength);
            } else {
                // one character added, so just replace that one
                char c = newValue.toCharArray()[newLength - 1];
                if (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
                    original.append(c);
                    masked.append(c);
                } else if (c == '\u2022') {

                } else {
                    masked.append('\u2022');
                    original.append(c);
                }
            }
            // this output is just for checking the state of the original
            System.out.println(original.toString() + "\t--->\t" + masked.toString());
            textProperty().set(masked.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here the `Main.java`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            PasswordArea passwordArea = new PasswordArea();
            root.getChildren().addAll(passwordArea);
            primaryStage.show();
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can achive the result of your code simply copying my `maskText()` code inside this change listener. The problems is that the `getText()` method, in this case, return the masked text and not the clear text that is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class PasswordArea extends TextArea {

    private final static List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();

    private final static List<KeyCode> allowedKeys = Arrays.asList(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCode.SPACE, KeyCode.BACK_SPACE, KeyCode.A, KeyCode.B, KeyCode.C, KeyCode.D, KeyCode.E, KeyCode.F,
            KeyCode.G, KeyCode.H, KeyCode.I, KeyCode.J, KeyCode.K, KeyCode.L, KeyCode.M, KeyCode.N, KeyCode.O, KeyCode.P, KeyCode.Q, KeyCode.R, KeyCode.S, KeyCode.T, KeyCode.V,
            KeyCode.W, KeyCode.X, KeyCode.Y, KeyCode.Z);

    public PasswordArea() {
        this.setEditable(false);
        this.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (!allowedKeys.contains(event.getCode())) {
                return;
            }
            KeyCombination ctrlDelete = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
            if(ctrlDelete.match(event)) {
                setPasswordText(getPasswordText());
                return;
            }
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case ENTER:
                    this.appendText("\n");
                    text.add("\n");
                    break;
                case SPACE:
                    this.appendText(" ");
                    text.add(" ");
                    break;
                case BACK_SPACE:
                    final int size = this.textProperty().length().get();
                    if (size > 0) {
                        this.deleteText(size - 1, size);
                        text.remove(text.size() - 1);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    this.appendText("" + '\u2022');
                    text.add(event.getText());
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    public String getPasswordText() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        text.forEach(builder::append);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public void setPasswordText(String setText) {
        text.clear();
        this.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < setText.length(); i++) {
            switch (setText.charAt(i)) {
                case ' ':
                    this.appendText(" ");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    this.appendText("\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    this.appendText("" + '\u2022');
                    break;
            }
        }
        text.add(setText);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Launch extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        PasswordArea area = new PasswordArea();
        Scene scene = new Scene(area, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

This is what I got, probably the cheapest way to do it.

Comment: What text do you get when you try `getText()` on the text area?

Comment: The list "text" contains all the keys

Comment: Maybe it's my fault that I didn't specify that I want that the `getText()` and `setText()` must work with the clear text. Just like `PasswordField` works.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I added getPasswordText() and setPasswordText() but this is also probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.
I found this solution. It works but it shoud be tested under certain conditions.
However this is the code, it involve only the skin.

```
public class PasswordAreaSkin extends TextAreaSkin {
    public PasswordAreaSkin(PasswordArea control) {
        Text textNode=getTextNode();
        textNode.textProperty().addListener(obs -> {
            textNode().setText(
                maskText(control.textProperty().getValueSafe()));
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected String maskText(String text) {
        int n = txt.length();
        StringBuilder passwordBuilder=new StringBuilder(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            passwordBuilder.append('\u2022'); //append 'bullet' char
        }

        return passwordBuilder.toString();
    }

    private Text getTextNode() {
        //WARNING: call ONLY in the constructor because 
        //children list could change
        Region content=
            ((Region)((ScrollPane)getChildren().get(0)).getContent());
        Group g=(Group)content.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(1);
        return (Text)g.getChildren().get(0);
    }
}
```

In this way, the text is masked in the control, but `getText()` return the clear text and `setText()` works with the clear text and in the ui mask it (that is what I was looking for)

The only problem is that I'm bound to an implementation detail, the position of the Text node in the children list.